# google drive api, export google slide as power point (ppt or pptx) - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I want to use the google apis to download a google slide as a power point presentation (ppt or pptx) to our node.js server. I have setup google drive api, and I have created a slide in my drive folder. I'm trying to use `drive.files.export` to download the slide, but since a slide isn't really a thing on windows or mac, I am trying to convert it to power point by setting the mimeType to `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`:

```
  const { drive } = await Google.getInstance();
  const fileId = 'SomeLongTemplateId';
  const fileName = 'test slide processing';
  console.log('exporting ppt');
  const ppt = await drive.files.export(  // report.js:343
    { fileId, mimeType: 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' },
    { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
  );
  return Buffer.from(ppt.data);
```

However, this throws and error and doesn't seem to work:

```
error: {
    message: ArrayBuffer {
      [Uint8Contents]: <7b 0a 20 22 65 72 72 6f 72 22 3a 20 7b 0a 20 20 22 65 72 72 6f 72 73 22 3a 20 5b 0a 20 20 20 7b 0a 20 20 20 20 22 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 22 3a 20 22 67 6c 6f 62 61 6c 22 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 22 72 65 61 73 6f 6e 22 3a 20 22 62 61 64 52 65 71 75 65 73 74 22 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 
22 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 22 3a 20 ... 195 more bytes>,
      byteLength: 295
    },
    stack: 'Error: [object ArrayBuffer]\n' +
      '    at Gaxios._request (C:\\Users\\rasmu\\Documents\\triggerz\\triggerz\\node_modules\\gaxios\\build\\src\\gaxios.js:129:23)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n' +
      '    at async JWT.requestAsync (C:\\Users\\rasmu\\Documents\\triggerz\\triggerz\\node_modules\\google-auth-library\\build\\src\\auth\\oauth2client.js:345:18)\n' +
      '    at async processionSlide (C:\\Users\\rasmu\\Documents\\triggerz\\triggerz\\entity-access\\src\\act\\report.js:343:15)'
  },
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't really say what the problem is, but it definitely doesn't work. I have also tried exporting as `pptx` using the mimeType `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` but this gave a similar error.

I am used to export pdf's using this technique, and it works like a charm, the only difference is that I export a doc (google docs) and use the mimeType `application/pdf`

In the web UI of google drive, I can right-click on the slide and choose "download" this, downloads a pptx file that I can open with both MS power point and Libre office. - so it would surprise me a lot is the google node.js api library can't export in the same manner.

Any ideas how I can export a slide as a presentation that works on windows/mac ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, when I saw the exportFormats with "About: get" of Drive API, the mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.presentation` (Google Slides) can be exported to the following mimeTypes.

```
"application/vnd.google-apps.presentation": [
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
  "application/pdf",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
  "text/plain"
],
```

By this, it seems that when the export method is used, Google Slides cannot be exported as `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`. By this, when I tested this, the error occurs. But from above exportFormats, it is found that when the mimeType of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` is used, the Google Slides can be exported as PPTX.

But from your question, you say as follows.

> Unfortunately, it doesn't really say what the problem is, but it definitely doesn't work. I have also tried exporting as `pptx` using the mimeType `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` but this gave a similar error.

When I tested your script using the mimeType of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`, no error occurs. So please modify your script as follows and test it again.

#### Modified script:

```js
const fileId = 'SomeLongTemplateId';
const fileName = "test slide processing";
console.log("exporting ppt");
const ppt = await drive.files.export(
  {
    fileId: fileId,
    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
  },
  { responseType: "arraybuffer" }
);
fs.writeFile("sample.pptx", Buffer.from(ppt.data), (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});

// return Buffer.from(ppt.data);
```

- When I tested this modified script, I could confirm that the file of `sample.pptx` can be created and the file can be opened as PPTX file.

#### Reference:

- [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)

Comment: Great! thanks, `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` does indeed work! I think what happened when I tried the first time was that I didn't select the full string, and accidentally missed a few chars when I pasted it.

Comment: @Rasmus Puls Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing you `responseType` to `stream` as recommended in this reference: [google api nodejs client [Help] Google Drive export example not working](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/help-google-drive-export-example-not-working)

```
const ppt = await drive.files.export(  // report.js:343
    { fileId, mimeType: 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' },
    { responseType: 'stream' }
  )
```

---

One workaround that I could suggest if the solution above still fails is to use [Drive.Files.Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get), Get the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) you your Google Slide file using its file id. Then get the `exportLinks` of your preferred mimeType.

### Sample (API explorer):

[image]

### Response:

```
{
 "name": "Untitled presentation",
 "exportLinks": {
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=13vwP4xQ_nVAHCPCuXI3GQKhMJrQ5goTfX7mh6qP5fKM&exportFormat=odp&resourcekey=0-nwpcI7sa0wRmreOT5Z6RJg",
  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=13vwP4xQ_nVAHCPCuXI3GQKhMJrQ5goTfX7mh6qP5fKM&exportFormat=pdf&resourcekey=0-nwpcI7sa0wRmreOT5Z6RJg",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=13vwP4xQ_nVAHCPCuXI3GQKhMJrQ5goTfX7mh6qP5fKM&exportFormat=pptx&resourcekey=0-nwpcI7sa0wRmreOT5Z6RJg",
  "text/plain": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=13vwP4xQ_nVAHCPCuXI3GQKhMJrQ5goTfX7mh6qP5fKM&exportFormat=txt&resourcekey=0-nwpcI7sa0wRmreOT5Z6RJg"
 }
}
```

- Access the export link using `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` as key. Download the file using the link.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Interesting approach, I am sure this would work as well. Though it would be an additional step (code wise), first getting the download link, then downloading and writing to disc. When requesting arrayBuffer I can write the response to disk as it comes in.